# How to solve $\sin(3x)+\cos(2x)={1\over2}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I have a trouble to continuing this problem.
My work so far :
$$\sin(3x)+\cos(2x)={1\over2}$$
I try using this :
$$\sin(3x)+\sin(90^\circ-2x)={1\over2}$$
$$2\sin\left({3x+90^\circ-2x\over2}\right)\cos\left({3x-90^\circ+2x\over2}\right)={1\over2}$$
$$4\sin\left({x+90^\circ\over2}\right)\cos\left({5x-90^\circ\over2}\right)=1$$
How to solving this equation ?
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall that:

$$\sin(a+b) + \sin(a-b) = 2\sin(a)\cos(b).$$

Let $a=x$ and $b=2x$. Then:

$$\sin(x+2x) + \sin(x-2x) = 2\sin(x)\cos(2x) \Rightarrow\\
\sin(3x) + \sin(-x) = 2\sin(x)\cos(2x) \Rightarrow\\
\sin(3x) - \sin(x) = 2\sin(x)\cos(2x) \Rightarrow\\
\sin(3x) = 2\sin(x)\cos(2x) + \sin(x).$$

At this point, your equation can be rewritten as follows:

$$\sin(3x)+\cos(2x)={1\over2} \Rightarrow\\
2\sin(x)\cos(2x) + \sin(x) + \cos(2x) = {1\over2}.$$

Now, recall that $\cos(2x) = 1 - 2\sin^2(x).$ Then:

$$2\sin(x)(1-2\sin^2(x)) + \sin(x) + (1-2\sin^2(x)) = {1\over2} \Rightarrow \\
2\sin(x)-4\sin^3(x)+\sin(x)+1-2\sin^2(x)  = {1\over2} \Rightarrow \\
8\sin^3(x)+4\sin^2(x)-6\sin(x)-1 = 0.$$

To solve the last line, read the answer by lab bhattacharjee, which suggests you to use the Cardano's formula for finding the roots of third order polynomial, obtained with the substitution $s = \sin(x)$. Also, the [Ruffini's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruffini%27s_rule) is a good method for finding the roots of polynomials.

Answer (score 4):

Write $\sin x=s$

$$\dfrac12=3s-4s^3+1-2s^2\iff 8s^3+4s^2-6s-1=0$$

Use [Cardano's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_equation#Depressed_cubic)

Comment: Why there is a cube appear ? Would you explain ?

Comment: @bambangnugroho, See http://mathcentral.uregina.ca/QQ/database/QQ.09.99/sara1.html

Comment: I still confused with Cardano's formula. I read it in wikipedia but i can not understand.

Comment: +1 for the Cardano's formula.

Answer (score 0):

Uae that $$\sin(3x)=3\sin(x)-4\sin^3(x)$$
$$\cos(2x)=1-2\sin^2(x)$$